# Generic Extension Method of List<T> does not remove nulls

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I'm trying to make a pretty simple extension method that just remove nulls from a list.

It looks like this:

```cs
private static List<T> RemoveNulls<T>(this List<T> list) where T : new()
{
    List<T> newList = list.FindAll(x => x != null);
    return newList;
}
```

Very simple really. I call it like this:

```cs
foundNeighbors.RemoveNulls();
```

Yet I still return a list with nulls some times. This should be impossible no? Am I missing something about extension methods?

Comment: It looks like you should be calling it like: `foundNeighbors = foundNeighbors.RemoveNulls();`

Comment: Can you say a bit about why you added a seemingly unnecessary default constructor constraint to `T`? That seems like an odd thing to do.

Comment: Can you also say a bit about why you used `FindAll` in an attempt to remove items from a list instead of `RemoveAll`?  I am interested to learn how people come to make these sorts of mistakes so that I can design better object models.

Comment: @EricLippert I believe it's because I just didn't remember that RemoveAll existed.

Comment: To the type question: Because I don't want lists with non-nullable types

Comment: @EricLippert, mind if I ask why compiler makes a copy of `list` in debug configuration if it doesn't plan to use it later https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwCwG5kCQRRysAzMgN7Lq3o12GwyHVJ0foBuAhgE6Y4qAM7oAvOgB2AUwDu6ADIBLYQBcAPFlQA+dJXQAiHsIBGBgDRSArgBsbloyYDGB9AF987TrQbffnLWEAOgAlaQBbAHsuaQA5WxthAAoASk9vHy9vADNIvmkeJwALJN4BNQElSUERFP8MwQBOJIq0wjdkDqRSMkEANkwYRRVVAFEAD1UqfyherAGobHQwqJj4u2F1ABVtJNUilWG1bd0bEbqsvXq6M7VQiOjpAEE7PfFdVXEJSQS2y663EA=

Comment: I'm not following your train of thought here, but I have not been keeping up with the details of the not-nullable reference type feature so possibly I am missing something. Suppose we have `class C { public C(int x){} ...}`, you are saying that `RemoveNulls<C>` should be illegal because C does not have a default constructor; is that your intention?

Comment: @kuskmen: I'm not following your train of thought either; which copy are you referring to that goes unused?  But generally speaking you should expect that the non-optimized code generation is *not optimized*, so an observation that it is not optimized is to be expected.

Comment: @kuskmen: If your question is "why does the compiler generate `X x = new X() { P = 1};` as though you wrote `X t = new X(); t.P = 1; X x = t;`, it's because that's what the specification says is the meaning of the initializer. The initializer has to run *before* the assignment to `x` because the code that executes in the initializer might be *observing* the state of `x`! It would be quite unexpected to see `x` assigned a value *before* the side effects of the right side of the assignment were complete.

Comment: @EricLippert Originally the code looked like this: `list.FindAll(x => !(x is null));` however I cannot do this, because T could be a non-nullable type. So going by this logic I added `where T : new()` and it still didn't work. So I changed it for `x != null`. The assumption was that I had to ensure someone could not call the method on a list of non-nullables for it to work.

Comment: @kuskmen: Consider a contrived example: `class X { static X x = new X() { P = 1 } public int P { set { Console.WriteLine(X.x == null); }  }`  We expect that this should have the semantics of `X t = new X(); t.P = 1; X.x = t;` so that the setter observes that `X.x` is still null. It would be very strange if this had the semantics of `X x = new X(); x.P = 1;` because now the assignment to `X.x` has happened *before* the completion of the right side of the assignment expression, and that fact is observable.

Comment: @OmniOwl: Thanks for that explanation. I need to play around with the non-nullable feature apparently. I will try your scenario and if I find out anything germane I'll report back.

Comment: @EricLippert Cheers. Could be cool to hear where you get with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your extension method creates and returns a brand new list without nulls, it does not mutate the calling object.

Use it like this instead:

```
foundNeighbors = foundNeighbors.RemoveNulls();
```

Comment: I tried to just manipulate the list itself in the extension method, but to no avail so I changed it up. I thought that since I was working on `this List<T>` it would work in the same way that `ref` does. Is that not he case?

Comment: @OmniOwl The Find method returns a new list with only the subset of items matching the given conditions (being not null in your case).

Comment: @hyvte I meant more that, I did this originally: `return list.FindAll(x => x != null);` but that still didn't work.

Comment: @OmniOwl, this is because that how it(FindAll) is designed to work, it takes "your" list as a reference and then makes new copy of it with the desired criteria in mind.

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks @kuskmen

Answer (score 4):

This is a matter of preferences but may I suggest

```
public static class ListExt
{
    public static void RemoveNulls<T>(this List<T> list)
        where T : new()
    {
        list.RemoveAll(t => t == null);
    }
}
```

It doesn't use any additional memory and it mutates `list` instance only, from what I see in the question and the comments this is what you are trying to achieve.

Later you can use it as you want

```
foundNeighbors.RemoveNulls();
```

and like I said this will change `foundNeighbors` directly.

@Edit: like others noticed if you want it to be faster (O(N)) you should use `RemoveAll` instead.

Comment: This is approach is O(N ^ 2), use `list.RemoveAll(i => i == null)`.

Comment: `RemoveAt` is O(N ^ 2) because of the `Array.Copy` ? Thanks a lot mate, thats a catch

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: No, it is O(n^2) because `RemoveAt` is O(n) in the size of the list and that operation is done up to O(n) times, so we multiply the ns.

Comment: Thanks guys for the catch, didn't understand the downvote I never said anything wrong, but its SO after all what can you expect :) Still, learned something new today!